# Does bluenrg-1 supports the voice over control?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluenrg

I'm working on a task to build the end to end communication on the Bluenrg1/2 chip,does it supports the audio commands and converts it to the digital signals, though it has the PDM streaming.
Could anyone give more insight on this.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please check FP-AUD-BVLINK1 software package:
https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/embedded-software/mcu-mpu-embedded-software/stm32-embedded-software/stm32-ode-function-pack-sw/fp-aud-bvlink1.html

The package is based on BlueNRG-MS which also works with BlueNRG-1 acting as a network coprocessor.

The user manual is evaluable:
https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00384318-getting-started-with-the-fpaudbvlink1-stm32-ode-function-pack-based-on-halfduplex-voice-streaming-over-ble-stmicroelectronics.pdf

It describes also the ASR (automatic speech recognition) demo with
Google Speech API (English) and iFlyTek MSC service (simplified Chinese)